# How to proceed past shipping in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping, theme, shopping-cart

We upgraded to the latest version of Magento but it's done some funny things.

We're unable to select a shipping method when trying to checkout

Any ideas how to resolve? Normally there would be a radio button which would be selected prior to clicking continue.

Kind regards,

Scott Hunt

[image: Issue example]

EDIT:
[image: Updated Issue upon click]

Comment: how many shipping method you have used

Comment: go to admin-> configuration -> sales ->shipping method ->and check all shipping method

Comment: Hello Vaibhav, I've tried enabling all shipping methods which makes the radio button appear. However this hasn't resolved the issue, I still cannot continue to the next step. When I click continue the button says "Loading next step" but then reverts to the same page. Any ideas?

Comment: I've added a picture as a sample, it then reverts (so it does nothing, and does not allow me to progress to the next ordering step). The website is [link](http://poolland.co.nz) if you would like to test it out to see what I mean

Comment: May be there is problem with js Please check browser console if there is any problem with js.Error will display in console

Comment: I had the console open in internet explorer while I did a trial check out but it did not detect any errors

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem after overriding the **checkout_index_index.xml** in the **Magento_Checkout** module.

If this is the case for you also, try removing this xml from your theme, then edit the xml so that it contains only the blocks you need changed, instead of the whole original file.

Comment: Sorry - I'm quite new to Magento - how do I do this?

Comment: First thing you have to do is remove the checkout_index_index.xml from your theme directory, which it should be something like: app/app/design/frontend/**VendorName**/**ThemeName**/Magento_Checkout/layout/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find the specified file - this indicates it's probably not the cause